# Questions About Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am learning about regular expressions, But I'm having trouble making sense of certain things. I am working on an assignment to use regex's to find various characters, and words in a string:

> Using the findall function, get all of the instances of non
>   alphanumeric characters in the string assigned to 'lorem_ipsum'
>
> Output to the console, the number of non-alphanumeric characters. 
>   Hint: use the len function. Use the ^ and [] regular expression
>   operator along with the findall() regular expression function.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'sit-:amet')
occurrance_sit_amet = pattern.findall(lorem_ipsum)
for match in occurrance_sit_amet:
  print (match)
```

Why would I use the len function? and even more puzzling, why would I use ^ and [], when they can only be used to find characters at the start of the string and characters in brackets? Also my code gave me this error:

> Cannot read property 'toISOString' of undefined -
>   9b2bb9d0-119a-11e8-95f3-4351563e5e1b

can someone explain what that means?

Comment: _"Why would I use the len function?"_ Because the assignment is to output the number of matches, which is not what your code is doing. _"why would I use ^ and [], when they can only be used to find characters at the start of the string and characters in brackets"_ Because that's the only way to get the correct output. You may have to (re-)read a regex tutorial if you think `[]` can only be used to find text in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what the hints are (though I admit they are quite misleading). When it says "use `^` and `[]`", it's not telling you to use a character class (`[]`) and a start of string anchor (`^`). It's telling you to combine the characters `[]` and `^` together to form a reverse character class `[^]`. Everything inside a reverse character class will not be matched.

The regex you need is this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

It means "everything ***but*** a-z, A-Z or 0-9"

Regarding the the `len` function, your task is to find how many non alphanumeric characters there are, isn't it? `findall` returns a list of the matches. That's why you need to find the length of the list to find out how many such characters there are.

Here is some code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
allMatches = pattern.findall(lorem_ipsum)
print(len(allMatches))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your questions:

1. Using `findall` returns `matches`, which is a list of all substrings that match your pattern.  So `len(matches)` should give you the "number of non-alphanumeric characters."
2. [`^` can be used in conjunction with `[]` to do a search for patterns NOT containing certain characters](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

A few issues with your regex that might be causing that error:

- The hyphen.  Hyphens denote a range when placed between two characters, so right now the regex is trying to find characters ranging from `t` to `:`, which doesn't mean anything.
- The alphabetical characters in the regex.  Aside from the colon, right now `r'sit-:amet'` matches a string composed of specific lowercase alphabetical letters one after another.  Even if the regex worked, this would not match your desired "non-alphanumeric" pattern.

What you need is a negative search for anything alphanumeric:

```
    [^A-Za-z0-9]
```

P.S. I highly recommend using [regexr](https://regexr.com/) whenever you have regex assingments.  It's a great way to check how pattern matching syntax works and test your regexs :)